# Nodejs and Amazon S3 friendship for a photo sharing application

Tags: performance, amazon-s3

We are currently developing a service to share photos about people's interests and we are using below technologies. (newbies btw.)

for backend

- Nodejs
- MongoDb
- Amazon S3

for frontend

- ios
- android
- web (Angularjs)

Storing and serving images is a big deal for our service (it must be fast). We are thinking about performance issues. We stored photos on mongodb first but we changed it into aws S3 then.
So,

```
1.our clients can upload images from the app(s) 
2.we are handling these images on nodejs and sending them to the aws S3 storage
3.s3 sends an url back to us
4.we save the url into the user's related post
5.so, when user wants to see his photos the app gets the photos from with their urls
6.finally we are getting images from S3 to the user directly.
```

Is this a good way to handle the situation? or is there a best way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :). Your question is more related to choice of network technology than a programming question, so is probably better suited to a sibling site like ServerFault. In general, if you want your images or assets to be delivered as fast as possible to the end user you would use a [Content Delivery Network (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) in front of S3. Amazon's CDN service is called [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) but there are many alternatives if you want to shop around on price.

Comment: Thank you @Stennie. I just read about CDN and i understand when to use it. Actually S3 is really fast but we don't know what it is going to be when we have thousands of users and so thousands of requests. I think we will make some stress tests to see what is happening.